# Spring Integration @Transformer input and output

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have an @InboundChannelAdapter which reads Files from file system and i am supposed to send them to a Transformer which would transform the file from Message < File > to Message < FileContent >
FileContent is my own class

Here is the code

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "importProcessChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000"))
public MessageSource<File> importFileComparatorMessageSource() {
    FileReadingMessageSource source = new FileReadingMessageSource();
    source.setDirectory(new File("C:\\FileTest"));
    CompositeFileListFilter<File> filterList = new CompositeFileListFilter<File>();
    filterList.addFilter(new SimplePatternFileListFilter("*.txt"));
    source.setFilter(filterList);
    return source;
}

@Bean
@Transformer(inputChannel = "importProcessChannel" , outputChannel = "splitFileChannel")
public Message<Filecontent> handleImportFile(Message<File>importFileMsg) {

    Filecontent rows = null;
    Message<Filecontent> msf = null;
    return msf;
    }
```

When starting the application i am getting the following error

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'handleImportFile' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.messaging.Message<java.io.File>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Can anyone give me a hand with this?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@Bean` from the `@Transformer`.